# SceneKit and COLLADA objects

Tags: ios, macos, scenekit

Is there a way to create a `SCNNode` starting from a `COLLADA` Object and then add the node as child of the rootNode?

I see the with `ScenKit` I can create a `SCNScene` starting from a `.dae` file using

`[SCNScene sceneWithURL:url options:nil error:&error];`

But I can't find a way to create a Node starting just from a dae.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to read objects from a file and insert them into another scene then you can create a scene source and get the entries from there.

Creating a scene source is very similar to creating a full scene

```
SCNSceneSource *source = [SCNSceneSource sceneSourceWithURL:url options:nil];
```

If you know the id of the node you are looking for then you can get it directly using

```
SCNNode *someNode = [source entryWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier" withClass:[SCNNode class]];
```

Otherwise you can ask for the identifiers for all the nodes and from there figure out what identifier you are looking for.

```
NSArray *nodeIdentifiers = [source identifiersOfEntriesWithClass:[SCNNode class]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a SCNScene instance created from a Collada file, you can retrieve any node with its name with:

SCNNode *myNode = [myScene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"aNodeName" recursively:YES];